# GAE/Goでデプロイ出来ない

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud, デプロイ

## 発生してる問題

GAE初心者です。GAE/Goでデプロイができません。
ビルドは完了するのですが、serviceのアップデートに時間がかかりすぎてtimeoutになってしまいます。
importするpackageをhttprouterのみにすると成功するので、外部packageの問題だと認識しています。
GAEは`syscall` や `unsafe`パッケージのインポートが許されていないことは調べて分かりました。
`golang.org/x/sys/unix`をインポートしているので、これが原因なのでしょうか？？
以下にて現状をお伝えするので、GAE/Goのよくある問題等、ヒントになる情報が欲しいです。
もし少しでも気になったことがあったらコメントして頂けますでしょうか？？
よろしくお願い致します。

### ディレクトリ構成

app.yamlはルート配下のappディレクトリに置いてあります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### app.yaml

```
runtime: go
env: flex
api_version: go1.8
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 2.3
  disk_size_gb: 20
readiness_check:
  app_start_timeout_sec: 3600
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: "インスタンス接続名"
```

### エラーメッセージ

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Operation 
[apps/profect_id/operations/24c2d890-3bb4-4c72-b037-e7cb57f85b7f] timed 
out. This operation may still be underway.
```

### インポートしているpackage

- github.com/jinzhu/inflection
- github.com/jinzhu/gorm
- github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
- github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql
- github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter

### デプロイツール

gcloud app deploy

Comment: syscall, unsafeが使えないのはStandardだけなので、Flexなら、特に問題ないんじゃないかなと思います。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/103279

Comment: @sinmetai
知らなかったです！ありがとうございます！

Comment: @htb
大変失礼しました。お恥ずかしながらマルチポストについて初めて知りました。削除いたします。

Comment: @RyoNakao コメントありがとうございます。削除する必要はないです。SOはマルチポストを禁止していません。両方のサイトに情報を共有して頂ければ回答しようとする人は助かります。

Comment: @htb 
ありがとうございます！では情報を共有いたします。
インポートするpackageを更新し、上記の5つまで減らしました。
デプロイには`gcloud app deploy`を使用しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 原因

`Updated health checks`を有効にしているのにも関わらず、`readiness_check`のエンドポイントを設定していないのが原因でした。

## GAEのヘルスチェック

GAEには`Legacy health checks`と`Updated health checks`があり、今回`Updated health checks`を有効にしていました。

## Updated health checks

Updated health checksは以下の２つを確認します。

### Liveness checks

VMとDockerコンテナが実行中であることを確認する

### Readiness checks

インスタンスがリクエストを受け入れられる状態かどうかをチェックします

今回は、上記のReadiness checksのエンドポイントをアプリケーションで設定していなかったため、サービスをアップデートする事ができませんでした。

＊間違いがあったらご指摘お願いします。